# Machines required Juju bootstrap

Tags: juju

```
root@ubuntu:~# juju status
environment: maas
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.18.4.1
    dns-name: BLD15-A4.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-7e161bda-f351-11e3-970e-f274b29c2565/
    series: precise
  "1":
    agent-state: pending
    dns-name: BLD02-A4.maas
    instance-id: manual:BLD02-A4.maas
    life: dying
    series: precise
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=16 mem=80521M
services: {}`
```

I have 5 nodes in MAAS environment do I need to manually bootstrap the other 4 machines via juju. By default if I run juju bootstrap it only install agent in one machine; And if I manually bootstrap machine id 1 - 4 then do I have to manually assign the machine ID when I deploy juju charm?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to create one bootstrap node for Juju. This is the node which will maintain and manage the rest of your Juju deployments to that environment.
Once you have "bootstrapped" an environment, you can simply deploy services using the Juju command. E.g.

```
juju deploy mysql
```

In your case, MAAS will select one of the remaining nodes to deploy the service on. If your nodes are big enough, you can deploy multiple services to each node (including the bootstrap node) by specifying extra options. For more information on this, please see the documentation (https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying).

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick Just one more issue Iam facing if is there any document i can follow to deploy openstack in two MAAS physical nodes. If I manually try to deply the services and let MAAS choose the nodes then for keystone it gives me the following error message 
    units:
      keystone/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "shared-db-relation-changed"'
        agent-version: 1.18.4
        life: dying
        machine: "0"
        public-address: xxxxx.maas
"hook failed: "shared-db-relation-changed" ERROR and it end up removing the relation and remove service.

Comment: Are they really huge nodes? what specs are they - i think limited resources may be the cause of your problems - like not allocating enough RAM to MySQL

Comment: The node have enough resources but I don't know how much resource each service requires. This particular error message I got as soon as I try to build the relation between keystone and mysql. I don't find a good document tation where I can install openstack in 2 nodes with no issues.

Comment: Right now the issue I am facing is that I can't install neutron - gateway in kvm while other services is in lxc mode